# Can anyone tell me why this HTML/CSS Carousel does not work in firefox?

Tags: html, css

I have this code that makes a pretty sweet carousel using only html and css. It works great in chrome, but not in firefox. Can anyone tell me why? I cannot click on the labels for other radio buttons, only the checked button.

Here is a code snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  user-select: none;
}

[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

#slider {
  height: 55vw;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

#slider label {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 1.2s ease;
}


#s1:checked ~ #slide4, #s2:checked ~ #slide5,
#s3:checked ~ #slide1, #s4:checked ~ #slide2,
#s5:checked ~ #slide3 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.37);
  transform: translate3d(-30%,0,-200px);
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide5, #s2:checked ~ #slide1,
#s3:checked ~ #slide2, #s4:checked ~ #slide3,
#s5:checked ~ #slide4 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transform: translate3d(-15%,0,-100px);
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide1, #s2:checked ~ #slide2,
#s3:checked ~ #slide3, #s4:checked ~ #slide4,
#s5:checked ~ #slide5 {
  box-shadow: 0 13px 25px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 11px 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.19);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide2, #s2:checked ~ #slide3,
#s3:checked ~ #slide4, #s4:checked ~ #slide5,
#s5:checked ~ #slide1 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transform: translate3d(15%,0,-100px);
}

#s1:checked ~ #slide3, #s2:checked ~ #slide4,
#s3:checked ~ #slide5, #s4:checked ~ #slide1,
#s5:checked ~ #slide2 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.37);
  transform: translate3d(30%,0,-200px);
}

#slide1 { background: #00BCD4 }
#slide2 { background: #4CAF50 }
#slide3 { background: #CDDC39 }
#slide4 { background: #FFC107 }
#slide5 { background: #FF5722 }
```

```html
<section id="slider"> 
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s1"> 
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s2"> 
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s3"checked> 
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s4"> 
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s5"> 

      <label for="s1" id="slide1"></label>
      <label for="s2" id="slide2"></label> 
      <label for="s3" id="slide3"></label> 
      <label for="s4" id="slide4"></label> 
      <label for="s5" id="slide5"></label> 
      </section>
```

I assume it has something to do with the css compatibility in firefox, but I am really not sure. I am pretty new to html/css so any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I have tried using this website https://caniuse.com/?compare=chrome+104,edge+104,firefox+103&compareCats=CSS,HTML5
to find any incompatibilities but I am still stumped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because of width instead of `label` give width to `#slider`

```css
* {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  user-select: none;
}

[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

#slider {
  height: 55vw;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#slider label {
  margin: auto;
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 1.2s ease;
}

#s1:checked~#slide4,
#s2:checked~#slide5,
#s3:checked~#slide1,
#s4:checked~#slide2,
#s5:checked~#slide3 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .37);
  transform: translate3d(-30%, 0, -200px);
}

#s1:checked~#slide5,
#s2:checked~#slide1,
#s3:checked~#slide2,
#s4:checked~#slide3,
#s5:checked~#slide4 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, -100px);
}

#s1:checked~#slide1,
#s2:checked~#slide2,
#s3:checked~#slide3,
#s4:checked~#slide4,
#s5:checked~#slide5 {
  box-shadow: 0 13px 25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0 11px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .19);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

#s1:checked~#slide2,
#s2:checked~#slide3,
#s3:checked~#slide4,
#s4:checked~#slide5,
#s5:checked~#slide1 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transform: translate3d(15%, 0, -100px);
}

#s1:checked~#slide3,
#s2:checked~#slide4,
#s3:checked~#slide5,
#s4:checked~#slide1,
#s5:checked~#slide2 {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .37);
  transform: translate3d(30%, 0, -200px);
}

#slide1 {
  background: #00BCD4
}

#slide2 {
  background: #4CAF50
}

#slide3 {
  background: #CDDC39
}

#slide4 {
  background: #FFC107
}

#slide5 {
  background: #FF5722
}
```

```html
<section id="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s1">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s2">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s3" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s4">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" id="s5">

  <label for="s1" id="slide1"></label>
  <label for="s2" id="slide2"></label>
  <label for="s3" id="slide3"></label>
  <label for="s4" id="slide4"></label>
  <label for="s5" id="slide5"></label>
</section>
```

Comment: I tried this and it does not seem to work

Comment: @AidanCuff It is working after changing  the width run my example in Mozila.

Comment: i see that the snippet runs in firefox, but when I run this code from a html file in firefox it seems to fail

Comment: actually after some fiddling I was able to get this to work. thank you kindly

Comment: @AidanCuff I have tried in html file only before posting on SW it's working perfectly fine. may be you are missing something please compare both css.